# How can i add results of two or more datetime interval in php or mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know how. please help me.
This is my code in php.
i dont know if it is possible in mysql statement

```
<?php
$start_date = new DateTime("2014-03-12 10:00:00");
$end_date = new DateTime("2014-03-12 18:00:00");
$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
echo "Result " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days , ".$interval->h." hours , ".$interval->i." minutes, ".$interval->s." seconds ";

$start_date2 = new DateTime("2014-03-12 10:00:00");
$end_date2 = new DateTime("2014-03-12 18:00:00");
$interval2 = $start_date2->diff($end_date2);
echo "Result " . $interval2->y . " years, " . $interval2->m." months, ".$interval2->d." days , ".$interval2->h." hours , ".$interval->i." minutes, ".$interval2->s." seconds ";?>
```

Thanks..

Comment: What is the result you expected?

Comment: the total time of the two intervals

Comment: What does that even mean? What is 6 years, 3 months, 20 days plus 9 years, 11 months, 31 days? You can determine the time elapsed between two points, but it doesn't make sense to add them together after that.

Comment: ok, forget about the code, but is there another way to do that? @tadman

Comment: What does March 3rd plus June 2nd equal? You can always work out the time in seconds, then divide into arbitrary year month and day units. You could also do the same thing with days. It just becomes misleading when you group that into months and years unless you just want a ballpark (e.g. assume 30-day months, 365 day years), and most MySQL functions are concerned with precision. You'll have to write your own method to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to have MySQL do the subtraction.

[MySQL timediff() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF('2008-12-31 23:59:59.000001',
    ->                 '2008-12-30 01:01:01.000002');
        -> '46:58:57.999999'
```

Contrary to comments, it *does* make sense to add and subtract time intervals. It just doesn't necessarily make sense to add months and days, because the interval `30 days` might be a month, less than a month, or more than a month. Library functions and intrinsic functions take these things into account.